# file_get_contents does not work for getting json from API in PHP 7

Tags: php, curl, file-io, php-7

I juz upgraded php from 5.6 to 7.2.

Before 7.2, both file_get_contents worked fine for getting json from API but after upgrade to 7.2,
it returned false.

file_get_contents($url) => false

The url is like this:
'https://username:password@project_domain/api/json/xxx/?param_a=' . $a . '&param_b='. $b

And I didn't even touch the default setting in php.ini which is probably related to file_get_contents:
allow_url_fopen = On

I did google for this but there is no straight answer for my problem.

What is the reason for this?

How to fix to it?

Thanks!

Comment: What else changed?  Is "urls as file handles" still enabled, etc?  What about SSL versions/certificates/etc?  Create a simple php file with just `phpinfo()` in it, check output to see how things are configured.

Comment: Checked phpinfo. Everything seems to be fine but I can't see anything in the options of php.ini like "urls as file handles".

Comment: It is allow_url_fopen 
 http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: I checked it. It is ON.

Comment: is openssl enabled?

Comment: Of Coz, it is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = "https://www.f5buddy.com/";

$options = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
          "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7\r\n"
));

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$file=htmlentities($file);
echo json_encode($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it with curl. It only worked when I skipped the ssl stuff. It is juz https to own project anyway so it shouldn't be a problem in security.

```
function getJsonFromAPI($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_decode($result);

    return $data;
}
```

Btw, I found out file_get_contents only worked for https to external url but not for https connection to the project itself. Any fix to that is appreciated.